# How to track Firestore data completely fetched or not?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, arraylist

```
mColRef.document(mUid).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            List<String> list =  (ArrayList<String>) documentSnapshot.get("contact");
        }
    });
```

ANDROID-JAVA:
I have an Array field in Firestore users_list, which may be contains 5k to 10k String values.
I want to make sure all data loaded completely in List list, and only then I can perform another operations. Please tell me how to know all data loaded successfully from Firestore array.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you perform a Firestor query, *all* of the results of that query are available when the onSuccess callback is is invoked.
The snapshot argument to the callback contains all of the document data, so when you call `documentSnapshot.get()`, the entire results are available.  There is no such thing as a partially loaded document.  It is all or nothing.